# React Native - TabNavigator isn't working inside ScrollView in Android

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview, react-navigation, tabcontrol

I have a TabNavigator inside the ScrollView, it is working fine in ios, but not in the android. TAB content is not visible and clicking on tabs doesnt work.
see working example on the link below.

Did try：

1. Giving a ScrollView add flex: 1,or height.
2. Giving a tab add flex: 1,or height.

   `export default class App extends React.Component {
     render() {
       return (
         <View style={styles.container}>
           <TabNavigator/>
           <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
             Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone!
             Save to get a shareable url.
           </Text>
           <View>
             <AssetExample/>
           </View>
           <ScrollView style={{height: 500}}>
             <TabNavigator/>
           </ScrollView>
         </View>
       );
     }
   }
   const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
     TabOne: Tab1,
     TabTwo: Tab2,
   }, {
     tabBarOptions: {
       activeTintColor: '#5B71F9',
       inactiveTintColor: '#888888',
       showIcon: false,
       labelStyle: {
         fontSize: 14
       },
       style: {
         backgroundColor: '#fff',
         shadowColor: '#fff',
         shadowOffset: {
           width: 0,
           height: 0,
         },
         shadowOpacity: 0,
         shadowRadius: 0,
         elevation: 0,
         height: 47,
         borderBottomWidth: 1,
         borderBottomColor: '#E8E8E8'
       },
       indicatorStyle: {
         height: 2,
         backgroundColor: '#5B71F9'
       }
     }
   });`

example： https://snack.expo.io/@15101668168/joyous-tortilla

Comment: please be more specific with the problem you are facing, and paste some code examples and specify what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hey, guys.
When the TabNavigator inside the ScrollView, TAB panel disappear, the links below you can see effect
[link] (https://snack.expo.io/@15101668168/joyous-tortilla)
@OriPrice

Comment: Please add specific code snippets to the question, plus what you have tried so far so we will have a directions.

Comment: ok, tks! @OriPrice

Comment: @赵锌泽 

The problem I see is coming from the content contentContainerStyle and style attribute. If you add only contentContainerStyle and with flex: 1, it fixes the problem. Note: DO NOT ADD styles attribute with any style property otherwise it will have some funny behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior:

The content of the scrollview TabNavigator under the ios and under the android can work normally.
Create Material TopTabNavigator with rolling and rolling of the page, rather than the TAB pane scroll.

**Example：**[Example](https://snack.expo.io/@15101668168/creatematerialtoptabnavigator-with-scrollview)

**Reference:** [Reference for the answer](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4987)

Comment: Yes, Listingzhao is me. 
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4987
But the problem is closed.

Comment: Yea, they gave you a solution, thats why its closed. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but the realization of the he is not my expectations, I feel this is a problem the react - native, and ask them questions.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21109

Comment: This answer doesn't work. What if I need to scroll the tab navigator along with other component as well. i.e. the parent is ScrollView. It has other components and Tab navigator. If the tab nav. is inside the scrollView, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you or not but you can try enclosing your TabNavigator component inside a view with some height and it should resolve your issue as it resolved mine.

```
<View style={{ height: 400 }}>
    <TabNavigator/>
</View>
```

Comment: When we're working with ScrollViews, one shouldn't be setting the height as a fixed constant of the scrollview because generally we set the height of the scrollview to be of `100%` of the it's parent. This doesn't actually solve the problem.